# MySQL how to GROUP SUM based on JOIN TABLE

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sum, mysql-8.0

I have **Three Table**, One **Master Table** and **Other Two Table** have relation with it.

### Below is the Three Table:

> **1. `ball_by_ball table`, this table holds full information by ball by ball:**

```
CREATE TABLE `ball_by_ball` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `over_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ball_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `innings_no` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `team_batting` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_bowling` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `striker_batting_position` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `striker` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `non_striker` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bowler` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Ball_Id_index` (`ball_id`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Innings_No_index` (`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index` (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Match_Id_index` (`match_id`),
  KEY `Ball_by_Ball_Over_Id_index` (`over_id`),
  KEY `Bowler` (`bowler`),
  KEY `Non_Striker` (`non_striker`),
  KEY `Striker` (`striker`),
  KEY `Team_Batting` (`team_batting`),
  KEY `Team_Bowling` (`team_bowling`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`non_striker`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`striker`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `match` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`team_batting`) REFERENCES `Team` (`Team_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`team_bowling`) REFERENCES `Team` (`Team_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ball_by_ball_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`bowler`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> **2. `batsman_scored`, this table holds batsman run scores by ball by ball:**

```
CREATE TABLE `batsman_scored` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `over_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ball_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `innings_no` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `runs_scored` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Ball_Id_index` (`ball_id`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Innings_No_index` (`innings_no`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_Over_Id_Ball_Id_Innings_No_index` (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Match_Id_index` (`match_id`),
  KEY `Batsman_Scored_Over_Id_index` (`over_id`),
  KEY `Runs_Scored` (`runs_scored`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`over_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`over_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ball_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`ball_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `batsman_scored_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`innings_no`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`innings_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> **3. `wicket_taken`, this table hold wicket fallen information by ball by ball:**

```
CREATE TABLE `wicket_taken` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `over_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `ball_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `innings_no` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `player_out` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kind_out` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `fielders` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`,`over_id`,`ball_id`,`innings_no`),
  KEY `Ball_Id` (`ball_id`),
  KEY `Fielders` (`fielders`),
  KEY `Innings_No` (`innings_no`),
  KEY `Kind_Out` (`kind_out`),
  KEY `Over_Id` (`over_id`),
  KEY `Player_Out` (`player_out`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`player_out`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_13` FOREIGN KEY (`over_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`over_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_14` FOREIGN KEY (`fielders`) REFERENCES `Player` (`Player_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_15` FOREIGN KEY (`ball_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`ball_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_19` FOREIGN KEY (`kind_out`) REFERENCES `Out_Type` (`Out_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`match_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `wicket_taken_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`innings_no`) REFERENCES `ball_by_ball` (`innings_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**This is my Query for joining three table:**

```
select *
from ball_by_ball a
       left join batsman_scored b using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
       left join wicket_taken wt using (match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no)
where a.match_id = 981018
  and a.innings_no = 1;
```

**Output: (First 24 Rows)**

```
+----------+---------+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| match_id | over_id | ball_id | innings_no | team_batting | team_bowling | striker_batting_position | striker | non_striker | bowler | runs_scored | player_out | kind_out | fielders |
+----------+---------+---------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
|   981018 |       1 |       1 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        1 |     254 |           2 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       1 |       2 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        1 |     254 |           2 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       1 |       3 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        1 |     254 |           2 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       1 |       4 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        2 |       2 |         254 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       1 |       5 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        2 |       2 |         254 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       1 |       6 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        2 |       2 |         254 |    270 |           1 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       2 |       1 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        2 |       2 |         254 |    140 |           0 |          2 |        1 |      110 |
|   981018 |       2 |       2 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        1 |     254 |          21 |    140 |           4 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       2 |       3 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        1 |     254 |          21 |    140 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       2 |       4 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        1 |     254 |          21 |    140 |           0 |        254 |        1 |      162 |
|   981018 |       2 |       5 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        3 |      88 |          21 |    140 |           1 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       2 |       6 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |    140 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       3 |       1 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        3 |      88 |          21 |    270 |           1 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       3 |       2 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       3 |       3 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       3 |       4 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       3 |       5 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |    270 |           1 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       3 |       6 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        3 |      88 |          21 |    270 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       4 |       1 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |     32 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       4 |       2 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |     32 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       4 |       3 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |     32 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       4 |       4 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        4 |      21 |          88 |     32 |           0 |         21 |        1 |      270 |
|   981018 |       4 |       5 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        5 |     147 |          88 |     32 |           0 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
|   981018 |       4 |       6 |          1 |           13 |            2 |                        5 |     147 |          88 |     32 |           1 |       NULL |     NULL |     NULL |
```

I want to sum `run_scored` row and group those by `player_out`. Which is actually called `Fall Of Wicket` from Cricket View. More easily i want to know which wicket had fallen and that time what was the score which i will get by summing all the `run_scored` row until `player_out` row value is `NOT NULL`.
I can do that by using loop and arrays where i will change the sum value when there will be no `NULL` value in `player_out` row but i don't know how can do that using MySQL query.

**My Require Output Will Be Like Below:**

```
player_out `SUM(run_score)`
2   1
254 4
21  3
.
.
```

> **So how can i do this.?**

Comment: Please do **not** use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) on StackExchange. Set up a fiddle (e.g. dbfiddle.uk) and you will likely get good/better results. Also, the screenshots don't demonstrate the `FOREIGN KEY` relationships between the tables - they would be very helpful!

Comment: @Vérace thanks for your suggestion, i will do that in next time.

Comment: @Vérace Here the `FOREIGN KEY` are `match_id, over_id, ball_id, innings_no`.

Comment: Great. What you could do is to replace your screenshots with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G;` for the three tables - that would be a start helping others to help you! This you can do easily from the mysql CLI programme. I'm fairly sure you can do it from a GUI also, but please post the results as text - which users can then copy/paste into whatever tool they wish to use. You can edit your own posts at all times. See the `Questions:` section of my profile here for tips on how to ask questions.

Comment: Focus on computing the `SUM` first.  Once you have that `SELECT` working, _then_ add in other stuff.  It may involve putting the `SUM` in a subquery.

Comment: @Vérace i updated my Question as you suggested and i have checked your profile and reads those Question section, hope  i will do better next time.

Comment: @RickJames yeah that's what i'm trying, here the summing is the main fact. because it has to be done based on `wicket_taken` table but i'm unable to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Rhidoy - Now I am puzzled.  I see two tables with identical `PRIMARY KEYs`.  What's the rationale?  Normally, one would have a single table.

Comment: If al of your tables have the same exact primary key, they should probably be the same table. That would simplify your query,

Comment: @RickJames actually all those three table has same primary key and you are right they are identically same table.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone yeah they are identically same table just separated for well organization. it's cricket database so those different table need. but i'm not sure how can i simplify my query to solve my problem.

Comment: `JOIN` + `GROUP BY` sometimes leads to "explosion" + "implosion" -- that is the JOIN explodes the number of rows involved, only to have the groupby shrink the number back.  However, the `SUM` is done with the "exploded" table.

Comment: @RickJames actually i'm not so much expert on database, i start learning database not more than 2months.  so still i'm learning, that's why i could not get you clearly.